# how to update brew formula when i update the relavant code

Tags: go, homebrew, homebrew-cask, goreleaser

I have created a custom brew formula for go binary. so when I update the main code repo, I need to manually update the homebrew-X formula to change the version or say update the shasum 256  of that.
can someone please help how can I update the shasum 256 and version auto?

Answer (score 1):

You can automate it with `goreleaser` help - [see `brew`](https://goreleaser.com/customization/homebrew/?h=brew)

here is a configuration example of how it can be used with `goreleaser` (note it's referring to the private repository).

```
brews:
  - name: app-cli
    homepage: 'https://github.com/xendit/app-cli'
    description: 'app-cli binary distribution using homebrew.'
    folder: Formula
    download_strategy: GitHubPrivateRepositoryReleaseDownloadStrategy
    custom_require: "lib/private_strategy"
    commit_author:
      name: goreleaserbot
      email: goreleaser@xendit.co
    tap:
      owner: username
      name: app-cli
    install: |
      bin.install "app-cli"
```

Goreleaser itself can be automated with any ci system.